# Set EditorFor value to DisplayFor value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I have a function that turns a row of DisplayFor's into EditorFor's. I am now trying to revert the EditorFor's back into DisplayFor's but with the new values.

Here is my View code. Each `<td>` is a column, and I am switching the span *item-display* and *item-field* visibility .hide() and .show() for their respective DisplayFor and EditorFor fields.

```
            <td class="col-lg-2">
                <span class="item-display">
                    <span style="font-size: 17px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="item-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </span>

            </td>


            <td class="col-lg-3">
                <span class="item-display">
                    <span style="font-size: 17px;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="item-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                </span>
            </td>


            <td class="col-lg-3">
                <span class="item-display">
                    <span style="font-size: 17px; font-style:italic">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="item-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </span>
            </td>


            <td class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
                <span style="visibility:hidden" class="ID">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</span>

                <span class="item-edit-button">
                    <button type="button" onclick="editFunction(this)" class=" btn btn-warning col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
                </span>

                <span class="item-save-button">
                    <button type="button" onclick="saveFunction(this)" class="btn btn-success col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Save</button>
                </span>

                <span class="item-delete-button">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-lg-4"><span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and here is my JQuery, right now it just turns my DisplayFor into EditorFor, then back to DisplayFor based on the button clicks (edit and save).

```
<script>
    function editFunction(element) {

        $(element).closest("span").hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();


        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .hide()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .show();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .hide()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .show();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .hide()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .show();

    }

    function saveFunction(element) {
        $(element).closest("span").hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").show();


        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .show()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .hide();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .show()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .hide();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .show()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .hide();

        var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
        var newName = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").text();
        var newRelease = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").text();
        var newDescription = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").text();


        alert("\n" + newID + "\n" + newName + "\n" + newRelease + "\n" + newDescription);



        @*$.post(
            '@Url.Action("UpdateTitle", "Movie")',
             {
                 'id': newID,
                 'name': newName
             },
            function (data) { },
            "json"
        );*@


    }
</script>
```

How can I capture the EditorFor value and put it into my DisplayFor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have stumbled upon the answer for those looking. You have to have a few things I was unaware of.

1. you need the input from the .val() of the EditorFor.
2. you then need to put that within a .html of your DisplayFor

So for my scenario

```
$(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").html(
$(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-field").find(":input:first").val());

            $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
                .show()
                .next("span.item-field")
                .hide();
```

So my DisplayFor has the `.html` which is like "set" and then I set it to the `.val()` of my EditorFor, followed by hiding the editor and showing the display. ;)

A simplified version would be something like. (only turns EditorFor into a DisplayFor with EditorFor's value)

```
<span class="CLASS_NAME_DISPLAYFOR">
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.someItem)
</span>
<span class="CLASS_NAME_EDITORFOR">
       @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.someItem)
</span>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">

            function myFunction(element) {
                $(element).find("span.CLASS_NAME_DISPLAYFOR").html($(element).find("span.CLASS_NAME_EDITORFOR").find(":input:first").val());
                $(element).find("span.CLASS_NAME_DISPLAYFOR")
                    .show()
                    .next("span.item-field")
                    .hide();
            }
```